# How to make font of code completion bigger in VSCode?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

When I enter "in", it shows "include" automatically. But the font is too small.
How do I make font of code completion bigger.

[image]

Comment: looks like an open issue - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2465